# Low-latency broadcast option via Youtube live API

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

The Broadcasts created via Youtube LiveStreaming API are default optimized for lower buffering. But on the main Youtube GUI, a new option has been introduced called "optimized for lower latency".

Any way we could access this using the API? Also, what would be the approximate delta change in latency? Would be great to access this via the Youtube APIs.

Comment: If the feature is not documented in the YouTube Live Streaming API docs, it's probably not accessible publicly.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a liveBroadcast, set `enableLowLatency` to `true` in the `contentDetails` object

Don't forget to include `contentDetails` in the `part` parameter to tell youtube that you want the `contentDetails` parameter persisted.

From non scientific observations on a couple of broadcasts so far, this setting seems to lower the latency from ~30s to ~15s